# Functions in $\mathbb R^2$ and double limits in Compositions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

I was looking at the double limits for two variable function in $\mathbb R$, and so I decided to partition the set of all such functions into two disjoint subsets as follows:

$$\mathbb F={\{f(x,y):(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2}\}=\mathbb F_i \cup \mathbb F_j \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\,\,(0)$$

$$\mathbb F_i(f(X,Y))={\Biggl\{f(x,y) \in \mathbb F:\lim _{x\rightarrow X } \left( \lim _{y\rightarrow Y}f \left( x,y
 \right)  \right) \neq \lim _{y\rightarrow Y} \left( \lim _{x
\rightarrow X }f \left( x,y \right)  \right)}\Biggr\}
\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(1)$$

$$\mathbb F_j(f(X,Y))={\Biggl\{f(x,y) \in \mathbb F:\lim _{x\rightarrow X } \left( \lim _{y\rightarrow Y}f \left( x,y
 \right)  \right) = \lim _{y\rightarrow Y} \left( \lim _{x
\rightarrow X }f \left( x,y \right)  \right)}\Biggr\}
\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\,(2)$$

Here are some examples of subsets of (1) and (2) for ${\{X,Y}\}={\{0,\infty}\}$:

$$   \left\{ {\frac {1}{xy}},xy,{{\rm e}^{xy}},{
{\rm e}^{-xy}},\ln  \left( xy \right) ,\tan \left( xy \right) 
 \right\} \subset \mathbb F_i \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\,\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(1e)$$

$$ \left\{ {x}^{y},{\frac {x}{y}},{\frac {y}{x}},\cos \left( {\frac {y}{
x}} \right) ,\sin \left( {\frac {y}{x}} \right) ,\tan \left( {\frac {x
}{y}} \right) ,\tan \left( {\frac {y}{x}} \right)  \right\} 
\subset \mathbb F_j\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\,\quad\quad\quad(2e)$$
And in observing the obvious trend that can be seen in these examples for many other functions, I made the following statements:

$$S_0:\lim _{x\rightarrow X} \left( \lim _{y\rightarrow Y}g \left( x,y
 \right)  \right) =\lim _{y\rightarrow Y} \left( \lim _{x\rightarrow X
}g \left( x,y \right)  \right)$$

$$S_1: X=\lim _{y\rightarrow Y}\Bigr(\frac{1}{Y}\Bigl)\, \lor \, X=\lim _{x\rightarrow X}\Bigr(\frac{1}{Y}\Bigl) $$
$$S_2:\lim _{x\rightarrow X} \left( \lim _{y\rightarrow Y}(f(g \left( x,y
 )\right))  \right) =\lim _{y\rightarrow Y} \left( \lim _{x\rightarrow X
}f(g \left( x,y \right))  \right) $$

$$S_0 \land S_1 \Rightarrow S_2$$

So my first question is:

1) Are the above assertions always the case, and what functions serve as counter examples?

And my second question is:

2) Does there exist any such case examples for which $\mathbb F_i \neq {\{\,}\}$ is true but $S_1$ is false?

Comment: Why use $i,j$ as subscripts?

Comment: what should I use?